# Add action to button programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to add an action to a button programmatically from within a custom class. However, I keep getting an error when I perform the action. I've read a lot about how to do this but am clearly making a mistake somewhere and can't figure out where.

The button is created in the first instance by dragging it onto the storyboard. I then control drag to the ViewControler.h file to get this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *testButtonForClass;
```

In ViewControler.m, I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    testClass *myClass = [[testClass alloc]init];
    myClass.myButton = self.testButtonForClass;
    [myClass assignActionTargets];
}
```

Below is the custom class Header and Implementation file.

**Header File**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

@interface testClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myButton;

-(void)assignActionTargets;

@end
```

**Implementation File**

```
#import "testClass.h"

@implementation testClass

-(void)assignActionTargets{    
    [self.myButton addTarget:
    self action:@selector(myButtonInnerTap) 
    forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)]; 
}

-(void)myButtonInnerTap{
     UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil 
     message:@"testClass says hello" 
     delegate:nil 
     cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [a show];
}

@end
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C and am not good at making use of the debugger. The programme compiles okay but when I click the button that I've assigned the class button to I get this: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x8), in Main.m

Comment: Add the exception breakpoint and see if you get any better information. see this question for how to set this up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: `otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];` also try to remove extra nil

Comment: can you paste the code of your controller. how you are calling function on button tap.

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke.  Specifically, look at the stack trace that is given to you when it crashes... set a break point at an early enough frame, and then step through the code from there to see where you are accessing invalid memory (most likely referencing a null pointer).

Comment: Thank you, everyone, I've added an exception breakpoint but it the error seems to be the same. I will update the code in the main question to describe how I assign the button in the ViewController class.

Comment: @Sparked You probably forgot to retain your testClass instance in view controller. Put `- (void)dealloc { NSLog(@"dealloc"); }` in testClass implementation just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `testClass` instance, but you don't keep a reference to, so it gets deallocated at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TestClass *myClass = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    myClass.myButton = self.testButtonForClass;
    [myClass assignActionTargets];

    // myClass gets deallocated here!
}
```

When the button is clicked, it tries to access the target you specify, but now that's a dangling pointer to an invalid memory segment, hence leading to a crash.

You have to keep a strong reference to `myClass` in order to keep it alive by the time the button is clicked. Declaring a strong property is a good way of achieving that.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) TestClass *myThingy;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myThingy = [[testClass alloc] init];
    self.myThingy.myButton = self.testButtonForClass;
    [self.myThingy assignActionTargets];
}
```

---

**Code style note**: Please, use some naming conventions. Class names should be capitalized (I already changed that in the above snippets, since it kills me...) and using `myClass` for a pointer to an *instance* of a class is plain disorienting.

Comment: This worked. Thank you, @Gabriele. I wasn't using the object scope properly, as you pointed out. I have one other question: What difference does changing 'nonatomic' to 'atomic' have in this instance?

Comment: No significant difference. `atomic` will produce accessor methods which use an internal lock, resulting in a slower implementation. `atomic` alone doesn't guarantee thread-safety anyway, so in the 99% of cases `nonatomic` is much more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

First, the double `nil` for the argument `otherButtonTitles` is "problematic". Reduce it to one.

Second, make sure the button and the object is properly retained by your calling class.

Finally, make sure via `NSLog` or breakpoints that the objects in question (custom object, button) are not nil.

Comment: Out of interest why is the double `nil` problematic?

Comment: I would think that a nil terminated list is expected. The behaviour with two `nil`s is undefined. Problematic, ugly, unnecessary, distracting - remove.

Comment: Yup I'll take the `undefined behaviour` argument.

Comment: `nil` terminated lists terminate as soon as the first `nil` is encountered, ignoring the rest. I agree that is ugly, unnecessary and distracting, but it is not problematic.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella this is why I questioned the comment originally but I think Mundi hit the nail on the head it's undefined, therefore it's not safe. If it works now it may not in future

Comment: @Paul.s well yes and no. Methods taking `nil`-terminated lists are parameters use `va_arg()` internally to extract their arguments in a loop. Such loop is interrupted whenever the parameter is not of the type expected by `va_arg()`, i.e. at the first `nil`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1405/_index.html for an example. Again, this is not good quality code, but it's also far away from being problematic.